# How do I can select the column names of a table in JSON form?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to return the column names of a table in JSON, where each column name is the key and the data type is the value.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(json_build_object(column_name, udt_name::regtype)) AS list 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'layer_1001'
```

That produces the following result:

```
[{"id": "integer"}, {"geom": "geometry"}, {"address": "text"}, {"start_date": "timestamp without time zone"}]
```

But I needed that the code produces the follow result:

```
{"id": "integer", "geom": "geometry", "address": "text", "start_date": "timestamp without time zone"}
```

Would anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you don't want json then don't use a json function, what about concatenating the result instead?

Comment: I want a JSON as result. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use either the function [`json_object` or `jsonb_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

they take two parameters, arrays of keys and values, and both must be serializable to text

```
SELECT 
  JSON_OBJECT(ARRAY_AGG(column_name::TEXT), ARRAY_AGG(udt_name::text)) 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'mytable'
```